# What happens if I violate the requirements imposed on ProgIDs?

Tags: windows, com, com-interop, ole, progid

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542719(VS.85).aspx) states that any ProgID must meet several formal requirements, length restriction included. However nothing is said about what happens if those are violated.

I found several places in our codebase where ProgIDs are longer than 39 characters, still everything seems to work allright for them, ProgIDFromCLSID() and CLSIDFromProgID() included.

Since violating those requirements is quite easy it would be very interesting to know what are the real possible consequences of such violations?

Comment: teh requirements violate you back. (sry, couldn't resist)

Comment: Looks like they don't want to violate me back immediately, but rather wait for something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you get is *undefined behavior.* This can range from normal functioning to crashes, kittens being eaten, firstborns sacrificed, &c.

More to the point, some requirements probably tell you a few things:

- *No more than 39 characters:* Other software might use a fixed-size buffer of 40 chars to store a ProgID. They would therefore only have the first 39 and might not find your ProgID if it's longer.
- *Not start with a digit; contain no punctuation except periods:* Again, this is a contract. Software may rely on this to verify ProgIDs it gets from somewhere that they are really ProgIDs and not something entirely different, for example.

Windows might not bite you immediately but other things might.

Comment: Yes, some program use the same buffer for progids and clsids (which is 38 bytes in the {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} form.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer yet -- I'm researching this problem, myself -- but I did come across this:

> It is common practice in managed code
>   to specify namespaces and typenames
>   that are verbose, but this can easily
>   exceed the maximum allowed length of a
>   ProgId (39 characters). If you do
>   this, there's no indication of the
>   problem until you try to register the
>   add-in with Excel – and even then,
>   Excel simply tells you that the add-in
>   is invalid, without providing any more
>   detail. To avoid this problem, you
>   should always specify a ProgId
>   explicitly, using the ProgId
>   attribute. Also remember that
>   underscores are legal in managed code,
>   but illegal in ProgIds.

in a [blog by Andrew Whitechapel](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/01/23/managed-automation-add-ins.aspx) which suggests that the limit may be more than just a convention enforced by programmers using short buffers.